# Braking issue on 2010 Ford Edge

Tags: ford, brakes, troubleshooting

The front drivers' side brake on my Ford Edge is having issues that appear to get worse the longer it is being driven in a single trip. There is vibration and the braking doesn't work momentarily. There is a metal on metal sound that gets louder when turning the wheel to the right while driving. The brake pads are less than a year old and appear to have no issues themselves. Wondering if anyone has any idea of what else the problem could be. 
Thanks for taking the time to help with this.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You said the brake pads *"appear to have no issues"*. Does that mean you have had the brakes apart to inspect them? Or just what you can see thru the wheel?

Comment: Metal sound could be a failing wheel bearing!